# How to pass a Matlab vector variable to a MuPAD function?

Tags: matlab, statistics, symbolic-math, mupad

I want to use the `stats::swGOFT` function in MuPAD. I have a numerical vector called `r`. I used

```
feval(symengine, 'stats::swGOFT', r);
```

The error was

> Error using mupadengine/feval (line 157)
>   MuPAD error: Error: Some data are of invalid type.

So I tried a more direct way, which worked:

```
feval(symengine, 'stats::swGOFT', 1,2,3,4);
```

But this didn't work:

```
feval(symengine, 'stats::swGOFT', [1,2,3,4]);
```

My variable `r` is a 1146-by-1 double vector. Obviously I can't manually input all the numbers. So, how to pass the vector variable `r` to the MuPAD function `stats::swGOFT`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MuPAD is not Matlab. From the current version documentation for [`stats::swGOFT`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/stats-swgoft.html), it appears that this function requires a [list](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/dom_list.html), as opposed to an [array](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/dom_array.html) (what Matlab uses). Many MuPAD functions automatically [`coerce`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/coerce.html) inputs to the desired format, but that doesn't seem to occur in this case. You have several options if you want to call this function from Matlab using numeric values – here's a simple one that will work for both floating point and symbolic numeric values:

```
r = randn(1146,1);
rStr = char(sym(r(:).'));
feval(symengine, 'stats::swGOFT', rStr(9:end-2))
```

This one should perform the string conversion more quickly for large datasets of floating point values using [`sprintf`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sprintf.html):

```
r = randn(1146,1);
rStr = ['[' sprintf('%.17g', r(1)) sprintf(',%.17g', r(2:end)) ']'];
feval(symengine, 'stats::swGOFT', rStr)
```

Since you're converting to a string yourself, you might as well convert the above to use [`evalin`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/evalin.html) directly:

```
r = randn(1146,1);
rStr = [ sprintf('%.17g', r(1)) sprintf(',%.17g', r(2:end)) ];
evalin(symengine, ['stats::swGOFT([' rStr '])'])
```

Comment: I don't understand this:  `stats::swGOFT([' rStr '])`. It appears that the Mupad grammar is different to Matlab. Otherwise the `[' rStr ']` inside  `stats::swGOFT()` doesn't make sense in Matlab. Perhaps this is why I didn't make it work in Mupad. But anyhow the code worked. Thanks!

Comment: Why there are spaces in front of and after rStr in `[' rStr ']`? I deleted the spaces and this `['rStr']` didn't work. So, `[' rStr ']` is equivalent to a list of numbers, e.g. `1, 2, 3, 4`. Tricky indeed.

Comment: @fyang: It's not `stats::swGOFT([' rStr '])`, but `['stats::swGOFT([' rStr '])']`. It's not tricky, it's just string concatenation. You're not calling `stats::swGOFT` directly, but rather telling `feval` or `evalin` to call it in the right context. You have to tell them the name of the function to call and specify any arguments. `feval` calls `evalin` under the hood in this case so it may be slightly more efficient to use it directly, but you have to pass it one long string. A bit [more here](http://mathworks.com/help/symbolic/call-built-in-mupad-functions-from-the-matlab-command-window.html).

Comment: If it helps, you can put commas in to further distinguish the elements of the character array: `['stats::swGOFT([', rStr, '])']`. This is equivalent to using [`strcat`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strcat.html) explicitly: `strcat('stats::swGOFT([', rStr, '])')`. Try printing out `rStr` and `['stats::swGOFT([' rStr '])']` for a small vector if you're still confused. Here's a bit more on [working with strings](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/creating-character-arrays.html) in Matlab.

Comment: Thanks! After you put the commas, I realised what you meant. It's the Matlab grammar. Just to concatenate 3 strings.